# Javascript Function Definitions

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was wondering why the Vector variable defined within this self executing javascript function doesn't require a var before it?  Is this just some other type of syntax for creating a named function?  Does this make it so we can't pass Vector as an argument to other functions?

```
(function() {
    Vector = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        return this;
    };

   //...snip   
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining `Vector` any other way would only create it within the scope of the closure; and would not be available outside the closure.

```
(function() {
    var Vector = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        return this;
    };

    function Vector() {
        // blah
    };

   //...snip   
})()

var something = new Vector() // ERROR :<
```

Nothing "requires" the `var` keyword; using it defines the scope the variable is available within. Not using it means the variable is created in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  Probably more an issue with VS2008 JS intellisense; but for some reason, Vector isn't showing up outside the self executing function...

Answer (score 3):

The code construct above makes Vector a global variable in the namespace, which might be OK since it is probably intended to be used as constructor.

I would not recommend adding to the global name space, actually take a look at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) its a very nice way to work with modular JS.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a variable without `var` makes it global.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector` in this case will be attached to the current `this` which would be `window`.  At least in the code you presented, there doesn't seem to be a need for the enclosing self executing function.